# Update multiple choice column values while creating new list item using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, client-object-model, csom

I have a requirement where I have to select the values of a choice field while creating a new item using CSOM. I'm able to update other fields, but for choice column, the value gets stored in the Specify your own value column, although the values are present in that particular choice column.

[image]

I assume my syntax for updating choice column is not correct.
Here is the code:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testList");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem["Name"] = "Sherlock Holmes";
oListItem["Phone"] = "0000000000";
oListItem["Address"] = "221B Baker Street";
oListItem["ChoiceOfCuisine"] = "Cajun,Persian cuisine,Zanzibari";
oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try below code.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testList");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
List<string> Items = new List<string>();
Items.Add("Cajun");
Items.Add("Persian cuisine");
Items.Add("Zanzibari");
oListItem["Name"] = "Sherlock Holmes";
oListItem["Phone"] = "0000000000";
oListItem["Address"] = "221B Baker Street";
oListItem["ChoiceOfCuisine"] = Items;
oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I think this would add the options to my list. The options are already there. I just want the given options to be saved to the list.

Comment: Please check edited answer. it's working or not

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass array like

```
            object[] fv = oListItem["ChoiceOfCuisine"] as object[];
            List<object> newChoiceOfCuisine = fv.ToList<object>();
            newChoiceOfCuisine.Add("Cajun");
            newChoiceOfCuisine.Add("Persian");
            newChoiceOfCuisine.Add("XYZ");
            oListItem["ChoiceOfCuisine"] = newLanguages.ToArray<object>();
```

hope this will work.

Comment: Hi Jinesh, I have to do it through client object model not javascript object model. I'm using C#.

Comment: please see edited answer. for more info visit this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43001021-799f-4e32-a47a-4dd7c309a759/multiple-choice-field-update?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Answer (score 2):

You can try it as below:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testList");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem["Name"] = "Sherlock Holmes";
oListItem["Phone"] = "0000000000";
oListItem["Address"] = "221B Baker Street";
oListItem["ChoiceOfCuisine"] = new string[] {"Cajun,Persian cuisine,Zanzibari"};
oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

update list item dynamically, tried and tested, For SharePoint Multi line choice column

List list = new List();
list .Add(";#" + strChoice);
list .Add(";#" + strChoice2);
string[] strSelectChoices = list.ToArray();
oListItem["ColumnName"] = strSelectChoices ;